# How to reload windows color settings after change of registry key?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, windows-registry, colors

I've got a little question regarding the color settings in windows 7:

Via Desktop-Right-Click -> Personalize -> Window Color -> Advances Settings

I'm able to change the color of the selected items. After I save the changes, windows updates automatically and the new color is shown.

Now I want to access these changes via a .cmd file. I already got the right Registry-Key for all needed settings but after I change the key, windows won't reload the settings and show the new color.

Thanks to google I already tried a lot of versions of >>RUNDLL32.EXE user32.dll,UpdatePerUserSystemParameters<< but it won't work at all.

How can I get windows to reload the color settings without logging off?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I have the same problem. I read about `WM_SETTINGCHANGE`, to be broadcasted to all windows http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/826fef09-8361-4bb6-b0db-33f8a24fb2bb/ , but I couldn't make it work. Maybe this link helps, in that case tell me if you figure it out!

Comment: A way to send messages without writing a C function is apparently autohotkey: http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/PostMessage.htm , but even there, no luck for me.