# Change Windows XP's system colors

Tags: windows-xp, colors

I'm looking for a program that lets me change the system colors in Windows XP. I'm talking about the colors in classic mode, not "Luna"-style themes.

I'm trying to set a darker theme but to make it work I need to nitpick two or three colors that Windows automatically chooses for me and doesn't let me change.

I basically need something better than Desktop->Properties->Appearance.
Do you know of such a program?

---

**Edit:** It's been one month, so it's safe to assume no one has an answer (who the hell still uses Windows XP anyway, right?). My only option at this point is creating an application of my own to deal with this. So I will mark this question as answered when [this one gets answered](https://superuser.com/questions/561019/how-to-reload-windows-color-settings-after-change-of-registry-key) (long shot, I know...)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Style XP](http://www.tgtsoft.com/products):

> Style XP is not a skinning engine. It uses Microsoft's built-in visual style engine, but enhances it by providing many useful tools. Style XP can import, select, rotate, and manage themes, visual styles, wallpapers,  logons, bootscreens, icons, and explorer bar. Future versions may support sounds, cursors, screensavers, and packages of all the above. How does it work? Instead of lines and gradients, the XP user interface natively supports the use of skinned bitmap controls (a visual style). This is Microsoft's own innovation. Style XP includes its own visual styles.

Comment: Just tested StyleXP and it does NOT do what I asked.
StyleXP is a theme manager, not a system color-changer.

Answer (score -1):

Nope but if you use classic you can change bar style by clicking advance but only some features with xp luna theme style